# Ajax form submit form issues. I can't get the correct value

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

In the following code, when I `alert` prior to my ajax call it executes as expected and  echo's out the correct information; however, when I try to pass the information through php, the data seems to be empty. What am I doing wrong in my php?

**Javascript**:

```
$('#submit_fourth').click(function(){
    //send information to server   
    var email = $('input#email').val();
    var hash = $('input#username').val();
    var type = $('input#type').val();
    var finish = "email=" + email + "hash=" + hash + "type=" + type;

    alert(finish);
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'process.php',
        data: finish,
        success: function(response) {
            alert('it worked!');
        }
    }); 
});
```

**PHP**:

```
<?php
     $to      = 'blanet910@yahoo.com';
     $subject = 'Hash testing requested';
     $message = $_POST['finish'];
     $headers = 'From: webmaster@hashtester.com' . "\r\n" .
         'Reply-To: webmaster@hashtester.com' . "\r\n" .
         'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: Could you not just pass finish as a query string instead?

Comment: `var_dump($message);` after you set it and paste the results.

Answer (score 3):

This is wrong:

```
var finish = "email=" + email + "hash=" + hash + "type=" + type;
```

Should be at least:

```
var finish = "email=" + email + "&hash=" + hash + "&type=" + type;
```

But to avoid problems with escaping of the data (which you are not doing...), it is probably better to use:

```
var finish = $("form").serialize();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass data in a plain object:

```
var email = $('input#email').val();
var hash = $('input#username').val();
var type = $('input#type').val();

$.ajax({
  cache: false,
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'process.php',
  data: {email: email, hash: hash, type: type},
  success: function(response) { alert('it worked!'); }
});
```

Comment: It's an object, not an array